# node-pre-gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I seemed to can't pass that stage

```
sudo npm install bcrypt
npm WARN engine bcrypt@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":">= 4.0.0"} (current:{"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine tar@4.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=4.5"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
-
> bcrypt@2.0.0 install /mnt/other/opt/3dcompare-v-dashboard/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

    const hlo = require('./high-level-opt.js')
^^^^^
node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

I tried several tips found around SA even to upgrade my node to 4.x but if I do this I am stuck to that error or some more popup, the project is based on a metor 1.2.1

thanks for any help appreciated

Comment: It looks like you need to update your `node` and `npm` versions. Try it by updating to latest available.

Comment: Then remove `node modules` directory and clear the npn cache using `npm cache clear --force` command. The install required packages using `npm install`.

Comment: @Suhas, I am still having the same error.

Comment: what `node` and `npm` version you are working on? It looks like the required dependencies are failing with lower `node` or `npm` versions.

Comment: @SuhasGavad after having trying several version of bcrypt. I installed bcrypt via   >  npm install bcrypt@0.8.0